# testing angular service with dependency in isolation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm testing an angular 4 service with a dependency on the Http service. The [testing guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#isolated-unit-tests) suggests using isolated unit tests where the service instance is created with the `new` keyword:

```
beforeEach(() => { service = new FancyService(); });
```

But when FancyService uses the Http service, I get the error

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

This makes sense as the Http service is in the FancyService constructor. So I add a new Http instance as below, but I get the same error.

```
beforeEach(() => { service = new FancyService(new Http())})
```

How can I make my service available in the tests?

Comment: Did you import HttpModule in your testing module? Also I suggest using injection in particular tests(so no new FancyService())

Comment: No, I've tried to keep it the same as the example in the link. The only difference is that now `FancyService` has a function returning `http.get(...`. So in the test I've just imported `Http` from `@angular/http` and plugged it in as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the dependency - use a stub service with nessesary methods.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

class FancyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getFancy(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('url');
  }
}

describe('FancyService', () => {
  let service: FancyService;

  it('can get fancy', () => {
    const fakeHttpClient = {
      get: () => {}
    };
    spyOn(fakeHttpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of('data'));

    service = new FancyService(<any>fakeHttpClient);

    service.getFancy().take(1).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        expect(result).toBe('data');
      }
    );
    expect(fakeHttpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(fakeHttpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('url');
  });
});
```

Comment: How would I do that for isolated tests?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the following error when setting `service = new FancyService(...`
Type '{ get: () => void; }' cannot be converted to type 'HttpClient'. Property 'handler' is missing in type '{ get: () => void; }'

Comment: Use `service = new FancyService(<any>fakeHttpClient);` instead